# Как в данном случаи задать setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Помогите разобраться со следующей задачей: "Необходимо установить `timeout` в данный запрос, чтобы при успешном выполнении, функция `successCallback(data)` выполнилась через минуту". 
Возможно ли такое реализовать?

```
function SaveStopToServer(applicantName, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.post('@Url.Action(nameof(...), "...")', { applicantName: applicantName })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                successCallback(data);
            }
                
            if (callReceivingMode) {
                window.location.href = "@DefaultSrc(false)";
            }
            //return;
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof errorCallback === 'function')
                errorCallback(jqXHR);
            if (callReceivingMode) {
                window.location.href = "@DefaultSrc(false)";
            }
        });
};
```

я пробовал так, то это не помогло
`setTimeout(successCallback, 60000, data)`

**EDIT_1**

 В `done` попадаю, в `if (typeof successCallback === 'function')` тоже, в консоли ошибок нет, `successCallback` - это функция (функционал к сожалению показать не могу), в `data` ошибок также нет

Comment: А в `done` попадаете? А в `if (typeof successCallback === 'function')` попадаете? А в консоли ошибки есть? Что у вас в `successCallback`? Может быть `data` неправильная и ваша ф-ия крашится? Ответы на все эти вопросы пожалуйста в сам вопрос, не в комментарии

Comment: _`setTimeout(successCallback, 60000, data)`_ - по идее, этот код правильный.

Comment: В добавок к ответу @Qwertiy. Если эту ф-ию вы всегда будете запускать через 6 секунд, то можете попробовать перенести `setTimeout` в саму функцию

Comment: Кстати, я кажется знаю, почему у вас не срабатывает. Если в `callReceivingMode` придёт `true`, то у вас произойдёт перезагрузка страницы, до того как сработает `successCallback`, потому он не будет запущен после перезагрузки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> setTimeout(successCallback, 60000, data)
> ```

Это должно работать.

---

Другой вариант - обернуть весь коллбэк:

```
function SaveStopToServer(applicantName, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.post('@Url.Action(nameof(...), "...")', { applicantName: applicantName })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
          successCallback(data);
        }
                
        if (callReceivingMode) {
          window.location.href = "@DefaultSrc(false)";
        }
      }, 60000);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (typeof errorCallback === 'function')
        errorCallback(jqXHR);

      if (callReceivingMode) {
        window.location.href = "@DefaultSrc(false)";
      }
    });
}
```